# asp.net expression builder within a larger string

Tags: asp.net, expressionbuilder

Is there a way to embed an expression builder within a larger string?

I'm trying to create a hyperlink where the URL includes an embedded expression. I tried writing

```
<asp:hyperlink id="add" runat="server" text="Add" NavigateUrl="~/admin/customer.aspx?code=<%$ AppSettings:salecode %>&action=add" />
```

But this didn't work -- the "<%$" and all just got included as text, no substitution was done.

Of course I could build the URL in code, it's no big deal, but I just wonder if it's possible to do this in the ASPX file somehow.

PS Just as a test, I tried putting

```
<asp:label id="test" runat="server" text="<%$ AppSettings:salecode %>" />
```

and that worked fine, so it's not that I'm mis-spelling the setting name or something dumb like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes around the `NavigateUrl` property:

```
NavigateUrl='~/admin/customer.aspx?code=<%$ AppSettings:salecode %>&action=add'
```

Comment: This doesn't work. the URL ends up being html encoded, something like - /admin/customer.aspx?code=%3C%$%20AppSettings:salecode%20%%3E&action=add in the example above. As far as I can tell there's no way to embed and expression builder within a string.